# How PHP warnings affect on Google SEO

Tags: php, seo

I have some warning messages when i run my PHP script at development environment.But there are no warning messages at production environment.

I am not sure if removing these PHP warnings increase my SEO score on Google.
If the answer is yes, should i remove them with correcting my codes, or just turning off PHP warnings is enough?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You should ask : _Will it influence on my google SERP rank_? SEO is forced attempts to cheat googles algorithms. Warnings should always be corrected. Remember, you create websites for people, not for searchengines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have warning messages on the production environment, why you think they could affect on your SEO status?

If you have them there, then it's better to solve the problem or just disable warning messages, that's better for the visitors at least, even if google doesn't care about them.

Also why you think solving problems to prevent throwing warning messages could make different results rather just simply disabling them? At the end you would not have those warning messages, right?

Nobody can see how you made that in your PHP code, they see the result ...

Comment: The warning messages won't show for visitors. But i am wonder if they have any bad side effect on my score or rank in google

Comment: Google bot is your visitor, right? search engines couldn't see anything more than you and me ...

Answer (score 2):

End user won't be able to see the warnings so they won't directly influence SEO. However, side effects of the warnings may lead to malformed markup, but it would be impossible to say whether or not that will ultimately affect a page ranking without seeing the specific situation.

Comment: Thank you...is there a document for discussing the subject?

Answer (score 2):

The warning message doesn't make any impact on SEO. Google will index your pages not your server logs.

But in term of best practice, it's better to find out and fix the warning.

Comment: `The warning message doesn't make any impact on SEO`
Do you know any document on web, which discussing the issue completely?

Comment: +1 for `Google will index your pages not your server logs.` ... I like that ... :)